# Calling a method not working

Tags: java, methods

so ive got

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Trying to open lock"); 
    System.out.println("Trying ");
    ComboLock numbers = new ComboLock();
    int number1 = numbers.ComboLock;
    `
```

and im trying to call ComboLock from this class

```
public class ComboLock {

private int number1, number2, number3;
private boolean locked;
public static final int SMALLEST_NUMBER = 1;
public static final int LARGEST_NUMBER = 39;

public ComboLock() {
    locked = true;
    Random rand = new Random();
    number1 = rand.nextInt(LARGEST_NUMBER - SMALLEST_NUMBER) + SMALLEST_NUMBER;
    number2 = rand.nextInt(LARGEST_NUMBER - SMALLEST_NUMBER) + SMALLEST_NUMBER;
    number3 = rand.nextInt(LARGEST_NUMBER - SMALLEST_NUMBER) + SMALLEST_NUMBER;
}
```

and im getting an error right where im trying to make number1.ComboLock(); saying it cannot find the symbol

Answer (score 3):

```
public ComboLock() {
```

Is a constructor and you are trying to access it as a function/method in

```
int number1 = numbers.ComboLock;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `ComboLock numbers = new ComboLock();`, it actually calls the ComboLock() function that you created. It's called a constructor and it only works with the function that has the same name as the class.

Answer (score 0):

```
public ComboLock() {
```

is the constructor and is static, you cannot call it using a object.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call the constructor, not a method. Being a constructor, it doesn't return a value, so there was no point assigning it's return value somewhere.

```
public class ComboLock {

    private int number1, number2, number3;
    private boolean locked;
    public static final int SMALLEST_NUMBER = 1;
    public static final int LARGEST_NUMBER = 39;

    public ComboLock() {
        locked = true;
        Random rand = new Random();
        number1 = rand.nextInt(LARGEST_NUMBER - SMALLEST_NUMBER) + SMALLEST_NUMBER;
        number2 = rand.nextInt(LARGEST_NUMBER - SMALLEST_NUMBER) + SMALLEST_NUMBER;
        number3 = rand.nextInt(LARGEST_NUMBER - SMALLEST_NUMBER) + SMALLEST_NUMBER;
    }
    public int getNumber1() {
        return number1;
    }
}
```

Call it like this:

```
ComboLock numbers = new ComboLock();
int number1 = numbers.getNumber1();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to do this:

```
int number1 = numbers.number1;
```

... which anyway won't work because the `number1` field is private.